# What is the meaning of each graph field when I use as.character(graph) in Igraph?

Tags: r, graph, igraph

At Igraph for R, if I have the following edges:

```
edges <- c(1,2, 2,3, 3,4, 4,5, 5,6, 6,7, 7,8, 8,9, 9,10, 10,11, 11,12)
```

and create a graph using `make_graph` as follows

```
g <- make_graph(edges)
```

and then I write the graph as a file as follows

```
write(as.character(g), "C:/output.txt")
```

I get as output in my file:

```
12
FALSE
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11)
list(c(1, 0, 1), list(), list(name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12")), list())
<environment>
```

What does each of these fields mean as graph properties?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is supposed to do anything in particular... if you want to get the information about the graph, you can use `print`:

```
> print(g)
IGRAPH 0560d23 D--- 12 11 -- 
+ edges from 0560d23:
 [1]  1-> 2  2-> 3  3-> 4  4-> 5  5-> 6  6-> 7  7-> 8  8-> 9  9->10 10->11 11->12
```

If you want to save the information about the graph to a file, you have to use `write_graph` like this:

```
write_graph(g, "C:/output.txt", "edgelist")
```

With the `edgelist` argument it will just store one row per edge.